# jQuery ajax does'nt call action class of struts

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts

I want to display database values when the dropdown value selected using jquery ajax in struts.But ajax does not call url.

My jsp page:

```
<!DOCTYPE unspecified PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
<html>
<head><title>welcome</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#show').click(function(event) {
      var name = $('#UserName').value;
       $.get('ajax.do', { userName : name }, function(responseText) {
                        $('#ajaxResponse').text(responseText);
                });
        });
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="details">
Select Name:
<select name="whatever" id="submit">
<logic:iterate id="slist" name="MapForm" property="list">
<option id="UserName" value="UserName"><bean:write name="slist" /></option>
</logic:iterate>
</select><br><br>
<button id="show">show details</button><br><br>
</div>
<div id="ajaxResponse">User info will be listed here...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My Action Class is:

```
package com.map;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class AjaxAction extends Action
{

        public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws Exception

          {

             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
             try{
               String username=request.getParameter("userName");
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               java.sql.Connection connection =           DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/nithya","root","root");
                java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
                String sql="select * from login where username='"+username+"' ";
                java.sql.ResultSet resultset =statement.executeQuery(sql) ;



              while(resultset.next()){ 

                    out.print("<FName:>"); resultset.getString("firstname");out.print("<br>");
                    out.print("<LName:>"); resultset.getString("lastname");out.print("<br>");
                    out.print("<Email:>"); resultset.getString("email");out.print("<br>");
                    out.print("<Mobile_num:>"); resultset.getString("phone");out.print("<br>");
                    out.print("<address:>"); resultset.getString("address");out.print("<br>");

                     } 

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                         out.println("wrong entry"+e);
                    }





                    return null;
            }

        }
```

In action class I use out.print().is there any other way to display?

Struts-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN" 

    "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd"> 
    <struts-config> 
    <form-beans> 
    <form-bean name="AjaxForm" type="com.map.AjaxForm"/>
    </form-beans>
     <action-mappings> 
      </forward>
      </action> 
     <action name="AjaxForm"  path="/ajax" type="com.map.AjaxAction">

     </action>

      </action-mappings> 

       </struts-config>
```

Comment: Are you getting any output when your run ajax.do file directly?

Comment: no...actually the action class not receive the parameter